# How to start recoding a AVCaptureSession in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

This is the method I'm trying to fire:

```
mMovieFileOutput?.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: URL(mov_path), recordingDelegate: self)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads
```

Dose anyone know what arguments I need?

Comment: The correct URL initializer for a path is `URL(fileURLWithPath: mov_path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of the valid initializers for URL.

Here is some basic Swift 3 code to demonstrate this.

```
        var videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString + ".mov"
        let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        videoFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath, recordingDelegate: self)
```

If you want to use some other URL initializer for some reason, just use a valid one. As @Anton said, URL(fileURLWithPath: "") is correct initializer for a path.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks that worked for the toOutputFileURL argument!
Tho I don't think the delegate is correct, I get this error:
Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): *** -[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:]

Comment: Ops forgot to start the session with startRunning(), it works!

Comment: Awesome :) If you can mark this answer as correct, it would be appreciated :)